# SequenceFile format files, read in Snowflake as external table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a method to read "SequenceFile" format in Snowflake? (https://dwgeek.com/hive-different-file-formats-text-sequence-rc-avro-orc-parquet-file.html)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.  Orc, Avro, and Parquet are supported, though.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.